# check if there are more than 2 opened of same activity in stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A which opens activity B, and activity B can open activity A,
i can not finish() these activities , what is the right solution to avoid overflowing and nested opening these activities ?

how to check if there are more than 2 opened instance of same activity in stack ?

Comment: you have to read first clearTop, singletask , singleInstance of intent ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a a couple of launchMode values you can use for an Activity depending on the type of behaviour you want for that activity when it goes to backstack and when it is in foreground..

If you don't want multiple instances of an Activity in the stack, use launchMode as **singleTask** in your AndroidManifest for your Activity declaration.

```
<activity
 android:name="ActivityA"
 android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

See the details about different types of launchMode here - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks